# Who else besides Doctor Doom remembered their time in Battleworld?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, dr-doom

I've read *Infamous Iron Man #1-#3* and it made me wonder if there're other characters beside Doctor Doom who remember their times in *Secret Wars*' Battleworld.

Are there any others so far?

Comment: Spider-Man since that's where he got he symbiote costume. Not certain about others.

Comment: @Broklynite Which Spider-Man did you refer to? Morales or Parker?

Comment: Parker. Back then, there was only one Spider-Man. No reimaginings, 2099s, clones which turn out to be the originals (Ben O'Reilly), zombies, and no radioactive bodily fluids killing MJ. Not to say it was therefore better- this was also the era of Spider-Man And Friends, after all. Edit: er...wait, we are talking about the 1980's Battleworld, yes? Was there a new one I'm unaware of? Assuming we are talking 80's, then Parker at least does explicitly refer to the Battleworld when discussing getting the new costume at least once or twice once he is back on earth.

Comment: I got suspicious when you mentioned Morales that there may have been a new one I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking the 1980's version (and there has not been a subsequent one I am unaware of) then at the very least Spider-Man does. As can be seen [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hE7KoT36-dI/VXt6b5JJacI/AAAAAAAAn_k/lyBvTq9Jg40/s1600/wsm1_2.jpg) where Peter Parker refers to the symbiote costume: "...feels as comfortable as the shape-shifting black one I got on [sic] the Secret Wars."

This is not a comprehensive answer, since you are arguably actually requesting a list of everybody who remembers the Secret Wars/ Battleworld, but at least it does show that yes, there are those who still remember besides Doom.

Edit: it looks like there WAS a 2015 Secret Wars I was unaware of. Please clarify which flavor of Secret Wars you are referring to :)

Comment: I referred to the 2015 version. I didn't even know there's the 80's version lol

Comment: @DaNoob ah, okay, sorry for the confusion.